# AngularJS 2 quickstart error -

Tags: angular

While installing Angularjs2 quick start I ran into following error any suggestions to solve this error? My node version is 8 and npm version is 5

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:132587
>
> npm ERR! xt","tsd":"latest"},"bin":{"tsc":"./bin/tsc","tsserver":"./bin/tsserv
>
> npm ERR!

Any Help?

Comment: Please mention the link of angular 2 quick start link ?

Answer (score 0):

I re installed node and installed
Angular from the following link
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart
I used git bash to install.May be because I used windows command prompt this error had crept up.
Now everything is working